# Sum up datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have my current datetime base on my local area, here is the code:

```
            indo = timezone('Asia/Jakarta')
            # print(pytz.all_timezones)
            indo.zone
            # print(indo.zone)
            loc_dt = indo.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
            print(loc_dt) # 2021-10-19 04:07:20.871283+07:00
```

and the result of `loc_dt` is `2021-10-19 04:07:20.871283+07:00`. I would like to sum up `04:07:20.871283` with `07:00`, so the result that I expect is: `11:07:20.871283`. anyone knows how to do that ?

Comment: Have you explored `timedelta` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-timedelta

Comment: Hi @JamesCook thanks for the information.. yeah I have, and found the answer by doing ```new_time = loc_dt + time_change```

Comment: glad you found your answer